# Connecting to specific Wi-Fi channels?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

My university Wi-Fi has multiple SSIDs with the same name, but broadcasting in different channels (as I receive signals from different routers at the same time). However, in my room my Wi-Fi disconnects often which I'm assuming is because it is connecting to a router with poor signal strength. Is there any way to manually choose the SSID channel that I wish to join?

Surprisingly, my Android phone doesn't face this problem and is able to maintain a stable connection. I don't think anything's wrong with my MacBook as I can connect normally at other places including the lobby of my dorm.

Answer (score 1):

In a network environment with multiple Wi-Fi access points with same SSID, iOS/macOS device automatically connect to the one with the best signal strength. This should happen automatically without any intervention from user side.

If you find the connection to be poor, go to Settings -> Wi-Fi (on iOS)/System Preferences -> Network (on macOS) and toggle Wi-Fi off and on again. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Not an iOS issue, I'm using a MacBook here

Comment: Answer is relevant for both iOS/macOS or any other Apple device. Updated the answer for macOS.